# "Rock, Paper, Scissors +" in F#

Tags: functional-programming, f#

During a discussion in a development chat, a user suggested to another (in the context of C# originally),

> **UserA:** Challenge: Create an implementation of RPS, and then show how it can be extended to include an unlockable option Bomb (blows up paper and rock, but scissors cuts the fuse - basically Paper+; AI that has Bomb uses it instead of Paper) with a minimum of fuss.
>
> **UserA:** Bonus: Make it so the game can be thus modified changing only data (constants, serialized fields, whatever).
>
> **UserB:** how would one unlock the Bomb?
>
> **UserA:** Basically "elsewhere" however you want. Could be an external property, could be an Interface or Serialized Field or parameter or whatever.

and since I'm interested in learning F# I decided to pick up the exercise. Along with that, I also tried to clean up the code for I/O handling, such that I could potentially swap a "player vs computer" game to "player vs player" or even "computer vs computer". I have published the script in [GitHub](https://github.com/kroltan/RockPaperScissorsBoom/blob/master/RockPaperScissorsBoom/Program.fs), but please find it pasted below too for convenience:

```
open System

type MatchResult =
    | Won
    | Lost
    | Draw

type Element =
    | Rock
    | Paper
    | Scissors
    | Bomb

type Player = {
    Pick: Element[] -> Element;
    AnnounceResult: MatchResult -> unit;
}

let victoriesOf element =
    match element with
    | Rock -> [Scissors]
    | Paper -> [Rock]
    | Scissors -> [Paper; Bomb]
    | Bomb -> [Rock; Paper]

let (!) (result: MatchResult) =
    match result with
    | Won -> Lost
    | Lost -> Won
    | x -> x

let evaluate player rival =
    let winsOver a b =
        victoriesOf a
        |> List.contains b
    match (winsOver player rival, winsOver rival player) with
    | (true, false) -> Won
    | (false, true) -> Lost
    | _ -> Draw

let parse options move =
    let cleanup (input: string) = input.ToLowerInvariant().Trim()
    let compare =
        string
        >> cleanup
        >> (=) move
    Seq.tryFind compare options

let runRound (a: Player) (b: Player) options =
    let aChoice = a.Pick options
    let bChoice = b.Pick options
    let result = evaluate aChoice bChoice
    a.AnnounceResult result
    b.AnnounceResult !result

let player = {
    Pick = fun options ->
        printfn "Choose one of %s:" (String.Join(", ", options))
        match parse options (Console.ReadLine()) with
        | Some(x) -> x
        | None -> failwith "Unknown choice!";
    AnnounceResult = fun result ->
        match result with
        | Won -> printfn "You won!"
        | Lost -> printfn "You lost!"
        | Draw -> printfn "It's a draw!"
}

let computer = 
    let rng = Random()
    {
        Pick = fun options -> 
            let choice = Array.item (rng.Next(options.Length)) options
            printfn "Computer chose %A" choice
            choice;
        AnnounceResult = fun _ -> ();
    }

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let validMoves = [|Rock; Paper; Scissors; Bomb|]

    while true do
        runRound player computer validMoves
    0
```

Since I'm new to ML-like languages, I'm looking for feedback on how I could better use the F# libraries, better model my state and data, and even how to make it more point-free. And if there are more idiomatic ways of writing any piece of code, please tell!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

F# is pretty pragmatic and multi-paradigm - you don't need to stick super hard to ML style code.

```fs
type Player = {
    Pick: Element[] -> Element;
    AnnounceResult: MatchResult -> unit;
}
```

Record fields should be lowercase (and you don't need the semicolons) - but in this case, [guidelines](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/style-guide/component-design-guidelines#use-interfaces-to-group-related-operations) suggest using interfaces over a record of functions. Interfaces have their own gotchas in F#, but on the whole are mostly better for this purpose, and also interop.

```fs
type Player =
    abstract Pick : Element[] -> Element
    abstract AnnounceResult : MatchResult -> unit
```

which makes your `player` (using object expressions and renaming `options` -> `moveOptions`):

```fs
let player =
    { new Player with
        member _.Pick moveOptions = 
            printfn "Choose one of %s:" (String.Join(", ", moveOptions))
            match parse moveOptions (Console.ReadLine()) with
            | Some x -> x
            | None -> failwith "Unknown choice!"
            
        member _.AnnounceResult result =
            match result with
            | Won -> printfn "You won!"
            | Lost -> printfn "You lost!"
            | Draw -> printfn "It's a draw!"
    }
```

---

```fs
let (!) (result: MatchResult) =
    match result with
    | Won -> Lost
    | Lost -> Won
    | x -> x
```

This would shadow the ref cell dereference operator - even though you don't use that here you may want to hide this somewhere closer to where you actually use it; if your module gets `open`ed it might break ref cells in consuming code. You could also stick it on the DU as a member:

```fs
type MatchResult =
    | Won
    | Lost
    | Draw
    member x.Not =
        match x with
        | Won -> Lost
        | Lost -> Won
        | Draw -> Draw
```

and then:

```fs
let runRound (a: Player) (b: Player) moveOptions =
    ...
    a.AnnounceResult result
    b.AnnounceResult result.Not
```

---

Changing some names around here helped me understand this bit better:

```fs
let parse moveOptions moveInput =
    let cleanup (input: string) = input.ToLowerInvariant().Trim()
    let isInput =
        string
        >> cleanup
        >> (=) moveInput
    Seq.tryFind isInput moveOptions
```

Which revealed you're calling `string` on your `Element[]` move options list on every player pick. You could just do this once (also, unless we really need `Array`s for interop or perf, `List`s are simpler to write and work with):

```fs
let cleanup (input: string) = input.ToLowerInvariant().Trim()

let main argv =
    let validMoveOptions =
        [ Rock; Paper; Scissors; Bomb ]
        |> List.map (string >> cleanup)
    ...
```

Or convert the input instead of the list of `Element`s and skip the compare stuff altogether:

```fs
let parseInput =
    let asElement =
        function
        | "rock" -> Rock
        | "paper" -> Paper
        | "scissors" -> Scissors
        | "bomb" -> Bomb
        | s -> failwithf "Unknown move! %s" s
    
    cleanup >> asElement
```

`player` becomes:

```fs
let player =
    { new Player with
        member _.Pick moveOptions =
            printfn "Choose one of %s:" (String.Join(", ", moveOptions))
            Console.ReadLine() |> parseInput
        member _.AnnounceResult result =
    ... same ...
    }
```

---

Both `victoriesOf` and `evaluate` are hard for me to understand, but I think you could rewrite it like this:

```fs
let (|>|) a b = // "beats" operator
    match a, b with
    | Rock, Scissors
    | Paper, Rock
    | Scissors, Paper
    | Scissors, Bomb
    | Bomb, Paper
    | Bomb, Rock -> true
    | _ -> false
    
let rockBeatsPaper = Rock |>| Paper
```

and `evaluate` becomes:

```fs
let evaluate player rival =
    match player |>| rival, rival |>| player with
    | true, false -> Won
    | false, true -> Lost
    | _ -> Draw
```

or as a member:

```fs
type Element =
    | Rock
    | Paper
    | Scissors
    | Bomb
    member x.Beats y =
        match x, y with
        ...
        
let evaluate player rival =
    match player.Beats rival, rival.Beats player with
    ...
```

---

If you want to go for that bonus goal, you could drop the `Element` DU altogether and just work with provided strings via say, cli:

```
> dotnet run -- -el rock -beats scissors -el paper -beats rock -el scissors -beats paper -beats bomb -el bomb -beats paper -beats rock
```

Most of the logic doesn't change, you just need to parse the input arguments and `parseInput` becomes just `cleanup`.

---

To summarize: convert your input to the model type rather than vice versa. The model types look good. The names chosen got pretty confusing, using 3 different names (move, Element, option) for the same thing made this code harder to understand at first read.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough review! I agree on converting input to data, I don't know what I was thinking at the time :) And I really like the "beats operator", much cleaner solution. That said, could you clarify how does the `(!) (result: MatchResult)` operator conflict with reference cells? I was under the impression that F# accepted multiple definitions if their parameters are different (in this case `MatchResult` vs `Ref<'a>`).

Comment: Yes that's normally doable, but you'd need to write it as a [static class member](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/operator-overloading).

`!` is unidiomatic in F# for negation, but also looks like an operator you simply can't overload.

You could maybe work around it with SRTP and op_Dereference, but I think it's more trouble than it's worth at that point. You could always use unary `-` (negative) instead: `static member (~-) (x: MatchResult)`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I was not aware of that. Unary negative seems like a neat substitute if I were to keep using the operator idea.